# Duplicate keystrokes on cshtml editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm having a strange problem in Visual Studio 2022, and would like to know if someone else faced it.

It only happens when editting .cshtml files, on Asp.net MVC projects, ocasionally when I press a key on the keyboard, the editor insert that same letter 2, sometimes 4 times. I need to restart my machine to solve it, but it will eventually return. The image bellow ilustrate the problem, I've typed `<div>` and got this result:

[image]

It doesn't happen on .cs, .js files, or in any other editor in my machine.

Comment: try to reinstall it, thanks

Comment: I think I solved the keystrokes duplication problem, when I was not even trying to fix it. I can't know if it was really the solution, but I don't want to get back to the old situation. It seems if I go to WinMerge change the file encoding from "01252 - Western European (Windows)" to "65001 - Unicode (UTF-8)", with BOM, problem becomes solved. After this change, I had to fix some French spelling where there were accents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have GitHub Copilot activated. If so, try deactivating it.

I was going nuts with this too, until I found out that it was GitHub Copilot that was doing it once in a while. I have not found a solution to it, other than deactivating Copilot.
You can see a thread on it here: https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/14206

Boa sorte ;-)

Comment: I'm going to try the solution to uncheck the option "Enable for HTMLProjection", as said in the link you sent, this way I don't have to disable CoPilot. E Obrigado ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, I uninstalled the Live Share component using Visual Studio Installer and modify Visual Studio. Then it got resolved.